# How to get memsiteid after adding account using yodlee fastlink

Tags: yodlee

hi i successfully added account using yodlee fast link.

my question is how i can get **memsiteid** or any other data which identify that which account is added.
is there is any api that use only usercontext and return memsiteid or account data.

i referred this link also but did't get any good hint so please can any one help me to bring out this problem.

https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Yodlee_FastLink_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Though you can get the memSiteAccId in the call back URL but for already added accounts you can use [getAllSiteAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) API to get all memSiteAccIDs.

Comment: Thanks @Apoorv for your quick help.I think it will work i will try it.And i have one more question in which you can help me.
1. I am able to generate fastlink url for add account without IAV using oauth but when i tried for iav fastlink its showing me yodlee page with error on that page **"Temporary technical problem Please try after some time"** .So is it problem in our url generation or its yodlee site problem.I also checked all parameters into url it looking right.Can you help me in this.

Comment: Hi @Apoorv i tried with [getAllSiteAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) but its showing error 415.and i also looked into callback url but i didn't find any memsiteid in that can you please show me how to find or get it.

Comment: @Er_js_sisodiya- Are you using HTTP POST? Can you share the details of the request? I think something is wrong with the params or URL.